# Two of three browsers show my webpage right. What is going on?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The first picture here shows how the webpage should be rendered (Chromium and Konqueror show it correctly)
[image: How it is supposed to be shown]
However here is how Iceweasel displays it:
[image]

And here is the webpage code, for the form section.

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-6">

    <form action="" method="post" name="newproyectform" class="form">     
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pname" class="control-label col-xs-12">Nombre del nuevo proyecto</label>
          <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname" id="pname">
          <span class="input-group-btn"> <button type="button" onclick="addNewProyect('msg_cont','pname')" class="btn btn btn-primary" >Agregar nuevo proyecto</button> </span>
          </div>
          <div class="container form-group col-lg-12" id="pname_msg"></div>
      </div>          
    </form>


    <form action="" method="post" name="newproyectform" class="form">     
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pname" class="control-label col-xs-12">Proyectos actuales</label>
          <div class="input-group">

          <select name="states" class="form-control" id="pname_del">
        <!--Se rellena con una función de js-->
          </select>

          <span class="input-group-btn"> <button type="button" onclick="" class="btn btn btn-primary" >Borrar proyecto</button> </span>
          </div>
          <div class="container form-group col-lg-12" id="pname_del_msg"></div>
      </div>          
    </form>

      </div>
```

Why is this happenning? Is this an iceweasel bug? Or did I do somehting wrong? As far as I can tell I'm using standard bootstrap code

Comment: Chromium & Konqueror share a layouting and rendering engine (Webkit). Historically Konqueror (kHTML) created Webkit, Safari (@apple) started contributing and maintaining it, Chrome/Chromium started contributing and maintaining as well until recently when Chrome decided to fork into Blink but they forked not because of layouting/rendering logic but because of the need to add their own process-management stuff.

Comment: When trying to do cross-browser checks make sure you are checking against different rendering engines. Chrome+Safari+Konqueror+Android+iOS use Webkit/Blink; Firefox uses Gecko; Internet Explorer uses Trident; Opera uses Presto.

Comment: Hmm, apparently Opera now uses Blink as a rendering engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the bootstrap grid system and form elements completely wrong. Please take a closer look on how to use it and the nesting of the classes.

Here is your code with proper markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">


    <form action="" method="post" name="newproyectform" class="form">     
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pname" class="control-label">Nombre del nuevo proyecto</label>
          <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" name="pname" id="pname" type="text">
          <span class="input-group-btn"> <button type="button" onclick="addNewProyect('msg_cont','pname')" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar nuevo proyecto</button> </span>
          </div>
          <div id="pname_msg"></div>
      </div>          
    </form>


    <form action="" method="post" name="newproyectform" class="form">     
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pname" class="control-label">Proyectos actuales</label>
          <div class="input-group">

          <select name="states" class="form-control" id="pname_del">
        <!--Se rellena con una función de js-->
          </select>

          <span class="input-group-btn"> <button type="button" onclick="" class="btn btn btn-primary">Borrar proyecto</button> </span>
          </div>
          <div id="pname_del_msg"></div>
      </div>          
    </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Working Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/nuqCa07YwT)

Comment: Thank you! This worked!! Although I don't understand why do you need to use two <div class="row">. Can you explain that to me?

Comment: you can't put `.col-xx-xx` classes directly within `.col-xx-xx` classes. You need to start a new `row` first. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting